Can liquid rubber be applied to asphalt on a concrete foundation?
First contractor rebuilt exterior foundation walls with concrete, said they next needed a concrete membrane, then disappeared. Second contractor said liquid rubber would work better because the walls were irregularly shaped. Agreed. Instead laborer applied asphalt. Now second contractor wants to apply liquid rubber to the asphalt. I read that LR won't bond to petroleum like in asphalt. I also read that muriatic acid can remove the asphalt, but wouldn't the concrete surface of the walls have to be redone? Please advise. This nightmare has been ongoing for five months.  Thank you.
The original issue we were trying to correct was re-doing crumbling sections of the house foundation. 1908 houses were built in the Pacific NW with lots of sand and river rock. It's not uncommon to "fix" this repeatedly in sections over time. First contractor did 3 sections last summer above ground by removing sand and rock going in about a couple feet and replacing that with a waterproof concrete mix of his own recipe. Then smoothing out the exterior wall presentation, painting them white. These two walls went underground, so he dug down about four feet and did the same process to the walls above and below ground. Before he disappeared, he said the next step was a waterproof membrane, but didn't define what product that was.
These walls had not leaked previously, but the NW is very wet and newly intensified storms have increased flooding in this neighborhood. Waterproofing is commonly done when redoing the foundation.
The second contractor was going to apply something called "Liquid Rubber Foundation Sealant" over the wall below ground. I will try and attach a photo but it just sees to show a moose. Instead what the laborer applied was APOC 301 Asphalt Roof & Foundation Coating. Online it says it works to damp proof not waterproof. I will see if I can attach photos.
Basically the question is how to remove the asphalt, or can the liquid rubber successfully be applied to the asphalt on the exterior foundation walls?
To add an image it says control + G but when I press "add image" after that only text appears. I will keep trying. This is what I get from both browse and copy:





Please post photos

What is "liquid rubber" ? is it pure rubber? or some chemical product just named that - what are the properties?

What is the original issue that you were trying to correct?

Are you sure it was asphalt?  Asphalt is not a good water sealer.  Nice thick tar has been used for sealing foundations.

I suspect "asphalt" is tar or bitumen.

What you are referring to as asphalt is an asphalt coating.  It states on the container that it is a roof and foundation coating.  So no ill effects can be expected from using it.
The "Liquid rubber" is also a foundation coating/ sealer.  Without knowing of a chemical incompatibility I can think of no reason why it cannot go directly over the asphalt coating product. There is no reason to "remove the asphalt" as there is no asphalt.
Read the info on both products to see if there is any warning of incompatibility.  If not, there should be no worries and you have 2 good coatings on your foundation.
